# Custom statement numbering using gather and align/aligned

Tags: equations, align, gather

Here is a proof in Latex, which renders like so:

[image]

I'm fairly pleased with the result, but I wish there were a way to turn the `(1)` and `(2)` into right-aligned elements instead of having to be manually written in.

Here is the source code for reference:

```
\begin{proof}[Proof.]
    Assumption ($\neg S$): $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.
\begin{align*}
    \sqrt{2} &= \frac{a}{b} \text{ $a, b$ in reduced form, $a, b \in \Z$, gcd($a, b$) = 1} \\
    2 &= \frac{a^{2}}{b^{2}} \\
    2b^{2} &= a^{2}
\end{align*}
(1) Since $a^{2} = 2b^{2}$, can say $a^{2}$ is even. With that, $a = 2k$ for $k in \Z$. Then:
\begin{align*}
    2b^{2} &= (2k)^{2} \\
    2b^{2} &= 4k^{2} \\ 
    b^{2} &= 2k^{2}
\end{align*}
(2) Similarly, since $b^{2} = 2k^{2}$, can say that $b^{2}$ (and $b$) is even.

Given (1) and (2), that both $a, b$ are even, then gcd($a, b$) $\geq$ 2.

\mathcom{Contradiction: gcd($a, b$) $\neq$ 1 when gcd($a, b$) $\geq$ 2.}
$\neg S$ ($\sqrt{2}$ is rational) is clearly false; because of this, $S$ must be true.
\[\therefore \sqrt{2} \text{ is irrational.}\]    
\end{proof}
```

A possible idea I had was to use `\gather` environments to define those statements and wrap the meddling `align*`s within them, but as I had assumed, the spacing did not turn out very well, though I was able to get my line numbers to work.

[image]

Source code for the possible workaround:

```
\begin{gather}
    \text{Statement} \\
\begin{align*}
    2b^{2} &= (2k)^{2} \\
    2b^{2} &= 4k^{2} \\ 
    b^{2} &= 2k^{2}
\end{align*} \\
    \text{Another statement}
\end{gather}
```

I then read up a little more and found out about `aligned`, so I replied `align*` with `aligned`. It fixed the spacing from `align*` but created a new issue - the `aligned` block was numbered, but I don't want it to be numbered.

[image]

Is there a way to work around the meddling `align*` environments so that it doesn't space according to the `gather` environments *and* have it so that it doesn't end up being added in as another numbered statement as with `aligned`? Thanks!

Comment: Strange idea... If you add an equation number to the statement, I assume you also want to only have that statement on the line, not have other elements like "With that, $a = 2k$ for $k in \Z$. Then:" Or what do you propose?

Comment: Thanks for the note - that was a good point to consider. Yes, your assumption is correct.

Comment: Real quick: How or where is `\mathcom` defined?

Comment: Forgot to define that - thanks for the heads up. `\mathcom` is defined as `{{\centering\small{{'textinput'\par}}}` where 'textinput' is where the text goes.

Comment: A small suggestion for code hygiene: Instead of `gcd($a, b$) $\geq$ 2`, please consider inputting `$\gcd(a, b) \geq 2$`.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest that you employ the machinery of the `enumitem` package -- specifically, its `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros -- to create a bespoke enumerated list whose `\item`s can be cross-referenced using the usual `\label`/`\ref` mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\newcommand\mathcom[1]{\begin{center}#1\end{center}}
\newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%% create a bespoke enumerate-like list:
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum,1]{label=\upshape(\arabic*), noitemsep, left=0pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
\begin{proof}
Assumption ($\neg S$): $\sqrt{2}$ is rational, i.e.,
\[
    \sqrt{2} = \frac{a}{b}\text{ for some integers $a, b \in \N$.} 
\]
W.l.o.g.\ we assume that $a$ and $b$ are in reduced form, i.e., $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.

\medskip
By assumption $\neg S$, $2 = a^{2}/b^{2}$ or $2b^{2} = a^{2}$. 

\begin{myenum}
\item \label{point:a} 
Since $a^{2} = 2b^{2}$, we deduce that $a^{2}$ and $a$ even. With that, $a = 2k$ for $k\in\N$. 

Then:
\begin{align*}
    2b^{2} &= (2k)^{2} \\
    2b^{2} &= 4k^{2} \\ 
    b^{2} &= 2k^{2}\,.
\end{align*}
\item \label{point:b} 
Similarly, since $b^{2} = 2k^{2}$, we deduce that $b^{2}$ and $b$ are even.
\end{myenum}

Given  points \ref{point:a} and \ref{point:b}, both $a$ and $b$ are even. Therefore $\gcd(a, b) \geq 2$.

\mathcom{\textsc{Contradiction}: $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ but also $\gcd(a, b) \geq2$.}

Thus, $\neg S$ (``$\sqrt{2}$ is rational'') is false. Because of this, $S$ must be true.
\[
\therefore\ \sqrt{2}\text{ is irrational.}\qedhere
\]    
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```